# Nested aggregation in Ent Query

Tags: go, ent

How can I write this simple SQL statement using the code generated by Ent?

```sql
select max(t.sum_score) from
                             (select sum(score) as "sum_score"
                              from matches
                              group by team) as t
```

I tried to use Custom SQL Modifiers feature flag as described [here](https://github.com/ent/ent/issues/3261)  but I can't figure out how to access the `sum_score` field from outside of the modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer from [a8m](https://github.com/a8m) the owner of the Ent Project (thank you!)

```
client.Match.Query().
    Aggregate(func(s *sql.Selector) string {
        const as = "max_score"
        s.GroupBy(match.FieldTeam).OrderBy(sql.Desc(as)).Limit(1)
        return sql.As(sql.Sum(match.FieldScore), as)
    }).
    IntX(ctx)
```

You can find the full answer [here](https://github.com/ent/ent/issues/3387) on the official GitHub repo.
I had to add `sql.Desc(as)` to get the maximum value.